# Цикл While

Tags: javascript, циклы

Привет.

**Бесконечный цикл!**

```
var x=109;  
while(x>30){
    if (x==45) continue;
    document.writeln(x);
    x-=4;
}
```

Почему получается бесконечный цикл через эту строчку `if (x==45) continue;`

Вот здесь все норм

```
var z=90;
for(z=90;z<100;z++){        
    if(z==93 ||z==95) continue;
    document.write(z);  
}
```

Пропускаются 2 числа. Аналогичное мне надо и в 1 цикле.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если `x` становится равным 45, оператором `continue` вы выходите из текущей итерации цикла, т.о. `x-=4;` не достигается, а т.к. он не достигается, то `x` так и остаётся быть равным 45, а если `x` становится равным 45, оператором `continue` вы выходите из текущей итерации...

В случае:

```
for(z=90;z<100;z++){
```

`z++` выполниться в любом случае, т.к. это нечто такое:

```
var z=90;
while(z<100){
    if(z==93 ||z==95) goto end;
    document.write(z);
    end: z++;  
}
```

> Аналогичное мне надо и в 1 цикле

вариант первый:

```
var x=113;  
while(x>30){        
    x-=4; // делать декримент перед условием
    if (x==45) continue;
    document.writeln(x);
}
```

вариант второй:

```
var x=109;  
while(x>30){
    if (x!=45) document.writeln(x); // поменять условие
    x-=4;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за отличные коменты и примеры